# Custom column sort with JQuery

Tags: jquery, sorting, html-table

I am making an MVC application and I want to sort a table client-side. I need to sort the columns in the table, using a custom sort-function that takes into account all the values in the column.

Using C# I can define a custom sort-function to sort column objects, but can I do something similar in JQuery?

Comment: Yes you can, using the `sort()` method

Comment: Try ready plugin: [http://tablesorter.com/docs/](http://tablesorter.com/docs/)

Comment: Yes.  Oh.. that *wasn't* the question?  You can use a third party library/plugin such as [datatables](https://datatables.net/).

Comment: Datatables will be your best friend for this... https://datatables.net/